# how do you escape single quotes in a mysql script?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, scripting

I need to create a trigger via mysql script

```
CREATE TRIGGER sync_new_oauth_sessions
    AFTER INSERT
    ON oauth_sessions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @s = 'INSERT INTO oauth_sessions_new(id, client_id, owner_type, owner_id, owner_id_new) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, CAST(NULLIF(?,'''') AS UNSIGNED))';
    -- INSERT INTO oauth_sessions_new(id, client_id, owner_type, owner_id, owner_id_new) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.client_id, NEW.owner_type, NEW.owner_id, CAST(NULLIF(NEW.owner_id,'') AS UNSIGNED));
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
    SET @sid = NEW.id;
    SET @s_client_id = NEW.client_id;
    SET @s_owner_type = NEW.owner_type;
    SET @s_owner_id = NEW.owner_id;
    SET @s_owner_id_new = NEW.owner_id;
    EXECUTE stmt2 USING @sid, @s_client_id, @s_owner_type, @s_owner_id, @s_owner_id_new;
END
```

This is the content of the script. I'm getting:
`Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If I do `\'\'` I have the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is the client language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct error message is

```
Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

> SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions

use

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sync_new_oauth_sessions
    AFTER INSERT
    ON oauth_sessions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO oauth_sessions_new(id, client_id, owner_type, owner_id, owner_id_new) VALUES (QUOTE(NEW.id), QUOTE(NEW.client_id), QUOTE(NEW.owner_type), QUOTE(NEW.owner_id), CAST(NULLIF(NEW.owner_id,'') AS UNSIGNED));
END
//
```

Comment: ``` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sync_new_oauth_sessions
```

Comment: workbench doesn't report any error, as you posted your code without `DELIMITER` remove them from the code

Comment: yes when I run it from a mysql client there is no problem, but I'm trying to run a `file.sql` that's where it breaks.

Comment: how do you run your sql file , when i send it from python ph c++ c# this works just fine. so you have to explain that

Comment: it's a bug in our migration system (using go with gorm)